# Change href of <a> tag to <input> tag onClick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do this:

```
<a class="a-link" href="/targetlink" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download</a>
<a class="a-link" href="/targetlink" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Alternative</a>
```

replaced automatically using JavaScript when the page has finished loading

```
<input type="button" class="a-link" onClick="parent.open('/targetlink')" formtarget="_blank">Download</input>
<input type="button" class="a-link" onClick="parent.open('/targetlink')" formtarget="_blank">Alternative</input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the document loads, loop over the targets, create a new element for each one found and replace the initial element with the new one:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('a-link').map(function(elem){
        var newElem = document.createElement('input');
        newElem.type = 'button';
        newElem.classList = item.classList;
        newElem.target    = item.target;
        newElem.addEventListener('click', function(){ /* define click event here */ })
    });

    elem.parentElement.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
});
```

It can be made more robust, but for the scope of your question, it should provide an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by removing the existing tag and creating another tag with the same attributes.

Or you can simply do this with `replaceWith()`.

```
$('#target').replaceWith('<newTag>' + $('target').html() +'</newTag>')
```